# constant export doesn't work on react application

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I was building simple React application from scratch using my own `babel`, `webpack` configuration without using `create-react-app`.

Css importing, React component, ES6 transpiling works well.
When I create constant file and import in my component file, an error occurs

I have moved constant to the component itself and it's working Ok.
but when i create constant file and import it from component, it's not working.

```
export default SKILLS = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'React',
    point: 8,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'Redux',
    point: 8,
  }
]
```

This is my constant file code

```
import SKILLS from '../data/skills';
```

And this is importing part in my component

Folder structure

```
|-data
|  |-skills.js
|-components
|  |-ResumeSection.js
```

This should work without error.

Error I got on dev console of chrome:

```
skills.js:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: SKILLS is not defined
    at eval (skills.js:2)
    at Module../src/data/skills.js (index_bundle.js:3921)
    at __webpack_require__ (index_bundle.js:727)
    at fn (index_bundle.js:101)
    at eval (ResumeSection.js:5)
    at Module../src/components/ResumeSection.js (index_bundle.js:3874)
    at __webpack_require__ (index_bundle.js:727)
    at fn (index_bundle.js:101)
    at eval (App.js:6)
    at Module../src/App.js (index_bundle.js:3828)
(anonymous) @ skills.js:2
./src/data/skills.js @ index_bundle.js:3921
__webpack_require__ @ index_bundle.js:727
fn @ index_bundle.js:101
(anonymous) @ ResumeSection.js:5
./src/components/ResumeSection.js @ index_bundle.js:3874
__webpack_require__ @ index_bundle.js:727
fn @ index_bundle.js:101
(anonymous) @ App.js:6
./src/App.js @ index_bundle.js:3828
__webpack_require__ @ index_bundle.js:727
fn @ index_bundle.js:101
(anonymous) @ index.js:6
./src/index.js @ index_bundle.js:3933
__webpack_require__ @ index_bundle.js:727
fn @ index_bundle.js:101
(anonymous) @ client:3
0 @ index_bundle.js:3944
__webpack_require__ @ index_bundle.js:727
(anonymous) @ index_bundle.js:794
(anonymous) @ index_bundle.js:797
```

my webpack configuration:

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, '/dist'),
    filename: 'index_bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ['babel-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/index.html'
    })
  ]
}
```

Comment: @MattOestreich, I tried inserting the `resolve` section in my `webpack.config.js` file, but it's not working.

Comment: I overlooked how you were exporting... @nhp supplied the answer.  That should work for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is invalid syntax, you have two options if you want to use a `default` export:

```
const SKILLS = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'React',
    point: 8,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'Redux',
    point: 8,
  }
]

export default SKILLS;
```

```
export default [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'React',
    point: 8,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'Redux',
    point: 8,
  }
]
```

Otherwise, you can use a named export:

```
export const SKILLS = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'React',
    point: 8,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'Redux',
    point: 8,
  }
]
```

But this will be used as `import { SKILLS } from "../resources/skill";`

Answer (score 1):

Export const SKILLS in your `skill.js`

```
export const SKILLS = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'React',
    point: 8,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'Redux',
    point: 8,
  }
]
```

Then import and use it

```
import {SKILLS} from "../resources/skill";

// do everything with SKILLS
```

Comment: This. Or you can just `export default [{ ... }];` (drop the name). Then import as `skills`.

Comment: Can't believe I overlooked that.. If you still want to use `export default` you would just do: `export default [...]` then to import you would do `import SKILLS from ....`

Comment: Good to know Matt

Comment: perfect! @JonathanBogdanovicz